# reset button in signup page is not working in android

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

I tried to make a signup page in android where I use a reset button that should clear all fields in the page. Please see the code below and correct it as my code is not working.

```
Button btnreset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnreset);

btnreset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {    
   public void restartActivity(Activity act){
     Intent intent=new Intent();
     act.finish();
     intent.setClass(act, act.getClass());
     act.startActivity(intent);
   }
}
```

this is an signup page and fields are first name,last name,user id,password.when user click on reset button it clear all the fields who's filled the user.I'm give a complete source code to you please check this:

```
                   package com.boyzcorn.android.fyp;

                   import android.app.Activity;
                   import android.os.Bundle;
                   import android.view.View;
                   import android.widget.Button;
                   import android.widget.EditText;
                   import android.widget.Toast;
                   import android.content.Intent;


            public class signup extends Activity{

          public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
             {
      super.onCreate(icicle);
      setContentView(R.layout.signup);
      Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClick2);
      Button btnreset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnreset);


      final EditText eText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstname);
      final EditText eText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lastname);
      final EditText eText3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.userid);
      final EditText eText4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
      b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View arg0) {

               {
                   if(eText1.getText().toString().equals("") ||eText2.getText().toString().equals("") || eText3.getText().toString().equals("") ||eText4.getText().toString().equals(""))
                   {
                   Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"Fill Empty Fields",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                   }
                   else
                   {
                   Intent i = new Intent(signup.this,login.class);
                   startActivity(i);
                   }
                   }
           }

                   });

   }    
 btnreset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {       
public void restartActivity(Activity act){

                Intent intent=new Intent();
                act.finish();
                intent.setClass(act, act.getClass());
                act.startActivity(intent);

    }
 }

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

        }

      }
```

Comment: what fields are you using in signup page and tell me exactly what do you require .

Answer (score 1):

You've only *defined* the function; you're not calling it. You will need to execute `restartActivity(signup.this)` from the `OnClickListener`.

Also, your intent will likely not execute, because its parent has been finished. Perhaps rearranging the lines of code might help, but a better solution would be having the parent activity start it. Try replacing the click listener with:

```
btnreset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Activity act = signup.this;
        Intent intent = new Intent(act, act.getClass());
        act.startActivity(intent);
        act.finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: i cannot understand your answered. I'm also paste a complete code could you correct to this code to reset button functionality. thanks in advance

Comment: Simply replace the click listener in `btnreset` with the above code.

Comment: hey this code was not working please correct that code and give i need to urgent this code.

Comment: your code give me an error that: multiple markers at this line,btnreset was not resolved a type.

Comment: You have inserted the snippet in the wrong place. From the code you've provided in the OP, replace the click listener with the click listener from the snippet above.

Comment: i also try to that mehtod but they not nothing:

btnreset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
Activity act = signup.this;
Intent intent = new Intent(act, act.signup());
startActivity(signup);
finish(signup);
}
);

Comment: thank you so much now this has been working i'm just adding on one mehtod in setonclicklisetner


 btnreset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     
     public void onClick(View v) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      
       Activity act = signup.this;
       Intent intent = new Intent(act, act.getClass());
       act.startActivity(intent);
       act.finish();
    
     }
     });

Comment: I see now that I overlooked the method declaration. Good to see you managed to get it working.